# What's default initial_state in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Usually, we would use `cell.zero_state` as the `initial_state` of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

Now, I'm wondering what's default `initial_state` in `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` if we don't set `initial_state`.

The most similar question I can find is [Setting initial state in dynamic RNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140870/setting-initial-state-in-dynamic-rnn)

But I can't understand what does scratch mean in the answer:

> If you don't set the initial_state, it will be trained from scratch as
> other weight matrices do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no `initial_state`, dynamic_rnn will try to call `cell.get_initial_state(inputs=None, batch_size=batch_size, dtype=dtype)` to set `initial_state`, and if `cell.get_initial_state` is not defined, `cell.zero_state` is used. See the source code of dynamic_rnn https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L671

For most default cell implementations, `cell.get_initial_state` function is defined the same as `cell.zero_state` if `inputs is none`. For example https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L281-L309

In conclusion, `cell.zero_state` is used whether you set the `initial_state` or not. But you can build your own cell and re-implement `cell.get_initial_state`.